# Virtualbox using VPN from host PC

Tags: virtualbox, vpn, ubuntu-server

Basically I have a VPN running on my pc and my virtualbox vm is using the vpn but I want it to use the local network. How do I do this?

Comment: Which VPN are you using?

Comment: Use NAT for the Guest to put it on a different subnet from the host. Put the VPN server on one machine and client on the other machine and connect it. Use the Host for the server so it can have a static IP for the Client to attach to.

Comment: @John uh I found out the sulution. just make the network adapter bridged.

Comment: That sounds like just a connection (that is, does not appear to be a regular VPN)